# DNS Server Software with Authenticated REST API

Tags: api, rest, dns

Does DNS server software exist with a built-in authenticated REST API for managing records?

Alternatively, is there a layer on top of any existing DNS software to manage DNS records?

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for: https://doc.powerdns.com/md/httpapi/README/

Answer (score 6):

[callsign](https://github.com/yaybu/callsign) is a mini DNS server written in Python that supplies a REST API. In order to authenticate your requests you can use iptables to restrict access to specific IP addresses.

If you 'd like something different for authentication, you can write your own API over either its command-line interface or its internal Python API by importing the package. It is licensed under the Apache license, so its quite permissive on what you can do with your code that uses it.

Answer (score 6):

You might try [Openstack Designate](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/designate/). It's a REST API that runs on top of a standard dns nameserver.

> - REST API for domain & record management
> - Multi-tenant
> - Integrated with Keystone for authentication
> - Framework in place to integrate with Nova and Neutron notifications (for auto-generated records)
> - Support for PowerDNS and Bind9 out of the box

Answer (score 2):

There's no DNS server software I know of with a built-in REST API.

The options I know of are:

1. use standard dynamic updates
2. use the IETF "Name Server Control Protocol", once it's finished and clients available (e.g. [DNSCCM](http://dnsccm.org/))

It wouldn't be hard to write a quick set of RESTful scripts that can produce dynamic update messages - I've seen it done using `Net::DNS` for Perl.